# Find first parent element with specific first-level descendant

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying get first parent (Only) of selected element which have Input type Checkbox as first-level descendant.

HTML

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(e) { 
  $(this)
    .parent()
    .parents("li:has(input[type='checkbox'])")
    .find(">span")
    .css("background-color", "yellow");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul class="UL1">
    <li class="LI1">
      <input class="checkbox1" type="checkbox" />
      <span>LI1</span>
      <ul class="UL2">
        <li class="LI3">
          <input class="checkbox2" type="checkbox" />
          <span>LI3</span>
        </li>
        <li class="LI4">
          <input class="checkbox3" type="checkbox" />
          <span>LI4</span>
          <ul class="UL3">
            <li class="LI5">
              <span>LI5</span>
            </li>
            <li class="LI6">              
              <span>LI6</span>
              <ul class="UL4">
                <li class="LI7">
                  <span>LI7</span>
                </li>
                <li class="LI8">
                  <input class="checkbox4" type="checkbox" />
                  <span>LI8</span>
                </li>
                <li class="LI9">
                  <span>LI9</span>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="LI10">
              <span>LI10</span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="LI11">
          <span>LI11</span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="LI12">
      <input class="checkbox5" type="checkbox" />
      <span>LI12</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

NOTE: In this code I am highlighting span only as an example, but my actual purpose of having parent with checkbox is different.

Here when selecting "LI8" checkbox, I need its parent that has Checkbox. according to this I should receive "LI4" but when I am using ".parents(). it is giving me all parents including "LI" not having Checkbox.

Does anybody know how can I get only first parent that has checkbox as first-level descendant? In my scenario on selection of "LI8", only "LI4" should return and "LI6" and "LI1" must ignore. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`li:has(input[type='checkbox'])` will select all `li`s that contain an `input` *at any level*.

Use the direct descendant selector (`>`) here: `.parents("li:has(>input[type='checkbox'])")` to select those `li`s that have a child `input`.

You can then limit the selection to a single item using `.first()`.

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(e) { 
  $(this)
    .parent()
    .parents("li:has(>input[type='checkbox'])")
    .first()
    .find(">span")
    .css("background-color", "yellow");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul class="UL1">
    <li class="LI1">
      <input class="checkbox1" type="checkbox" />
      <span>LI1</span>
      <ul class="UL2">
        <li class="LI3">
          <input class="checkbox2" type="checkbox" />
          <span>LI3</span>
        </li>
        <li class="LI4">
          <input class="checkbox3" type="checkbox" />
          <span>LI4</span>
          <ul class="UL3">
            <li class="LI5">
              <span>LI5</span>
            </li>
            <li class="LI6">              
              <span>LI6</span>
              <ul class="UL4">
                <li class="LI7">
                  <span>LI7</span>
                </li>
                <li class="LI8">
                  <input class="checkbox4" type="checkbox" />
                  <span>LI8</span>
                </li>
                <li class="LI9">
                  <span>LI9</span>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="LI10">
              <span>LI10</span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="LI11">
          <span>LI11</span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="LI12">
      <input class="checkbox5" type="checkbox" />
      <span>LI12</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I was so close with lack of knowledge. Thank you so much @Turnip to make me clear about the concept. It is working as I expected. Still lot to learn. :)